# backbone-form: how to show the jquery dialog for list-item editing over a colorbox dialog?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, backbone.js

I everybody,
I guess my quesiton is trivial but I'm getting stuck and aI need to share my doubts.

I use backbone.js and backbone-form (thanks to Charles Davison for creating this great tool).

I open the backbone-form inside a colorbox dialog, and it works fine. Here's the code:

```
        [...]
        this.form=new Backbone.Form({
            data: json_infos.RI, //Data to populate the form with
            schema: self.getSchema(json_infos.RI)
            }).render();
        $(this.form.el).prepend("<center><b>"+self.renderIMG()+self.model.get('ri_name')+"</b></center>").append('<div id="updatebtn">OK, Save all Changes!</div>');
        $(this.form.el).delegate('#updatebtn','click',  this.saveRI);

        $.colorbox({
            html:self.form.el,
            transition: "elastic",
            speed:400,
            scrolling: true,
            width: "650px",
            height: "600px"
            });
        },
```

In this popup box containing the form I've the problem:  when I want to add/remove/update an element of  a list, another jquery dialog is opened but **NOT OVER THE COLORBOX**.

I read many jquery documentation on DOM traversing, selectors, and I also individuated the code which I suppose should be modified, it's in the  jquery-ui-editors.js plugin, at lines 348, the 'openEditor' function

```
    openEditor: function(data, callback) {
        var self = this,
            schema = this.schema,
            listType = schema.listType || 'Text';

        var editor = Form.helpers.createEditor(listType, {
            key: '',
            schema: schema,
            value: data,
         }).render();


        var container = $(this.editorTemplate());

        //~ $(self.el).append($('.bbf-list-editor', container).html(editor.el));
        $('.bbf-list-editor', container).html(editor.el);

        var close = function() {
            container.dialog('close');

            editor.remove();
            container.remove();
        };


        $(container).dialog({
            resizable:  false,
            modal:      true,
            width:      500,
            title:      data ? 'Edit item' : 'New item',
            buttons: {
                'OK': function() {
                    callback(editor.getValue());
                    close();
                }, 
                'Cancel': close
            }
        });
    },
```

In this latter code I don't understand where and how we say to javascript "please create the element under the body tag and pop this up".

I need, indeed, to open it not over the 'body' but over the parent of the element which triggers the dialog.

Can anybody help me? 
If you need more details I'll be glad to add them.
Thanks in advance.

**------------UPDATE------------------**

I solved the issue using the z-index, as suggested by Sander.

The z-index must be modified **NOT IN THE CSS** but in the  part of the code where the popup is opened. So simply add

```
zIndex:     100000000,
```

in the jquery-ui popup options in jquery-ui-editors line 371.

Comment: i'm not sure, as i don't have the time to test it out, but this might be fixable with css, your modal opens but its under the colorbox? this might be fixable, by changing the z-index from either of the two popup s in the CSS files of jquery-ui or colorbox. if i had more time now, i'd test it myself but i bet this can be fixed that way

Comment: thanks for the fast answer, unfortunately it's not that simple. I tried with z-index at more than 1000 but it doesn't work. The basic problem is that I can't figure out how to use the form in the colorbox as the parent for the jquery dialog in the DOM.

Comment: the line towards the bottom of your second code block "$(container).dialog({" is what causes the box to open.  It's running off of $(container) which points to the method this.editorTemplate().  Without seeing the code in how you're trying to pop up the second box, as well as the code for the editorTemplate() method, it's difficult to pin point your issue.  Can you add that information?

Comment: @ryanmarc you are right. I send you the link to the code (it's too long to include it in the answer) specifying the lines where you can find the `editorTemplate` function. I had a look at it. It creates a template with mustache js (some nested divs).

anyway..the code is at https://github.com/powmedia/backbone-forms/blob/master/src/jquery-ui-editors.js   the function is at **line 155**, it uses the `createTemplate` function which is https://github.com/powmedia/backbone-forms/blob/master/src/backbone-forms.js   at **line 50** . does it help?

Comment: I finally decided to modify backbone-form in its source. So, my problem is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue using the z-index, as suggested by Sander.

The z-index must be modified NOT IN THE CSS but in the part of the code where the popup is opened. So simply add

zIndex:     100000000, 
in the jquery-ui popup options in jquery-ui-editors line 371.